# Can not upgrade postgis 2.5 to 3.0.1 for postgresql 11 on ubuntu

Tags: postgis

I need to upgrade my PostgreSQL 11 to PostgreSQL 12 with PostGIT 2.5 to 3.0.1.

I tried to install PostGIS 3 for PostgreSQL 11 on Ubuntu server to upgrade PostGIS first, before upgrading PostgreSQL.

I run

```
apt-get install postgresql-10-postgis-3
```

and get the error:

```
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  postgresql-10-postgis-3 postgresql-10-postgis-3-scripts
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 403 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,883 kB of archives.
After this operation, 30.0 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg/main amd64 postgresql-10-postgis-3-scripts all 3.0.1+dfsg-4.pgdg16.04+1 [1,052 kB]
Get:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt xenial-pgdg/main amd64 postgresql-10-postgis-3 amd64 3.0.1+dfsg-4.pgdg16.04+1 [831 kB]
Fetched 1,883 kB in 19s (97.0 kB/s)                                            
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-10-postgis-3-scripts.
(Reading database ... 175146 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-10-postgis-3-scripts_3.0.1+dfsg-4.pgdg16.04+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-10-postgis-3-scripts (3.0.1+dfsg-4.pgdg16.04+1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-10-postgis-3-scripts_3.0.1+dfsg-4.pgdg16.04+1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/postgresql/10/applications/shp2pgsql-gui.desktop', which is also in package postgresql-10-postgis-2.5-scripts 2.5.4+dfsg-1.pgdg16.04+1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Selecting previously unselected package postgresql-10-postgis-3.
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-10-postgis-3_3.0.1+dfsg-4.pgdg16.04+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-10-postgis-3 (3.0.1+dfsg-4.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Processing triggers for postgresql-common (216.pgdg16.04+1) ...
Building PostgreSQL dictionaries from installed myspell/hunspell packages...
  en_us
Removing obsolete dictionary files:
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-10-postgis-3-scripts_3.0.1+dfsg-4.pgdg16.04+1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Anybody faced such issue? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you have to uninstall 2.5 first?

Comment: Hello Laurenz, As you said, I removed postgis 2.5 first using apt-get --purge remove postgis 2-5. And installed postgis 3.0. Now I can instal postgis 3. However can not update postgis to 3.0 in existing database. ALTER EXTENSION postgis
 UPDATE TO "3.0.1";  I got error , 
ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.5": No such file or directory
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function _postgis_drop_function_if_needed(text,text) line 6 at FOR over SELECT rows
SQL state: 58P01

Comment: Thanks Laurenz for your hint. I removed postgis 2-5 first then tried to install postgis 3. and it worked.  I got error as above while updating extension however I resolved it by copying postgis file in same folder with old name. cp /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/postgis-3.so    /usr/lib/postgresql/11/lib/postgis-2.5.so  and same for postgis_topology.so file

Comment: Thanks Laurenz, my issue is resolved now.

Comment: Right, that is what the documentation recommends.